# Length of string returned by strtok()

Tags: c

I want to find length of word from string. When i use strlen(split) out of while loop it's ok. But when i use it from loop i have segmentation fault error. What's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[] = "Hello world!";
    char* word = strtok(string, " ");
    printf("%d\n", strlen(word));
    while(split != NULL) {
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        printf("%d\n", strlen(word ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check that `strtok` didn't return `NULL` before calling `strlen`

From the `strtok` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) (my emphasis)

> Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string
>   containing the next token. This string does not include the delimiting
>   byte. **If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.**

```
while(word != NULL) {
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (word != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", strlen(word ));
    }
}
```

Note that there was also a typo in your code.  The `while` loop should test `word` rather than `split`.